# How do I analyze a three factor ANOVA without replication in R?

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design, independence, pseudorepliction

This summer, I conducted a growth chamber experiment testing the effects of the projected climate change conditions on the growth and survival of newly germinated seedlings of Acadian forest tree species. I built 6 growth chambers, each with a unique combination of treatments:

Chamber 1: baseline Fredericton temp, 900 ppm CO2

Chamber 2: baseline Fredericton temp +3˚C, 900 ppm CO2

Chamber 3: baseline Fredericton temp +6˚C, 900 ppm CO2

Chamber 4: baseline Fredericton temp, ambient CO2

Chamber 5: baseline Fredericton temp +3˚C, ambient CO2

Chamber 6: baseline Fredericton temp +6˚C, ambient CO2

Each chamber has both drought and “normal” soil moisture regimes (one per side of each chamber), so temperature, CO2 and soil moisture are fully crossed (basically 12 unique treatments because each chamber is split into 2 soil moisture regimes). Within each of the 12 treatments, I have 135 balsam fir seedlings (i'll just talk about one species for the sake of simplicity) divided into three 45-cell trays. This means I technically have only 1 replicate for each of the 12 unique treatments for every measurement type (e.g., total height growth). For example, for the drought soil moisture regime in chamber 1, I would have to average the total seedling height growth of all 135 balsam fir seedlings and that would be my replicate in order to avoid pseudoreplication since they're all nested in chamber 1. This leads me to my question: how do I analyze a three factor ANOVA without replication in R? The three explanatory variables are CO2, temp and soil moisture and one of the response variables is, for example, total height growth.

My current model looks like this:

```
> model <- aov(height ~ temp*moist*co2, data)
> anova(model)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: height
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
temp              2 107797   53899 58.6180 < 2.2e-16 ***
co2               1  48756   48756 53.0253 6.531e-13 ***
moist             1   1033    1033  1.1231  0.289501    
temp:co2          2   5680    2840  3.0889  0.045973 *  
temp:moist        2  10747    5373  5.8438  0.002995 ** 
co2:moist         1  18886   18886 20.5395 6.526e-06 ***
temp:co2:moist    2  12539    6270  6.8185  0.001143 ** 
Residuals      1030 947073     919                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

As you can see the Df for Residuals is pretty high because I'm basically saying that every seedling is a replicate (pseudoreplication). If I follow the proper replication rules, the average seedling height per chamber is the true replicate since seedlings are nested in chambers. Then the code looks like this:

```
> data2 <- aggregate(height~temp+moist+co2, data=sdata, mean)
> data2
   temp    moist     co2    height
1     0 baseline 900 ppm  91.86207
2    +3 baseline 900 ppm 112.93103
3    +6 baseline 900 ppm 118.59770
4     0  drought 900 ppm 106.69318
5    +3  drought 900 ppm 124.37500
6    +6  drought 900 ppm 123.62069
7     0 baseline 400 ppm  95.81818
8    +3 baseline 400 ppm  93.89773
9    +6 baseline 400 ppm 118.22093
10    0  drought 400 ppm  76.04598
11   +3  drought 400 ppm 104.53488
12   +6  drought 400 ppm 107.63855
> model2 <- aov(height~temp*co2*moist, data=data2)
> anova(model2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: height
               Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
temp            2 1237.47  618.73               
co2             1  559.29  559.29               
moist           1   11.18   11.18               
temp:co2        2   63.51   31.75               
temp:moist      2  124.55   62.27               
co2:moist       1  216.88  216.88               
temp:co2:moist  2  143.51   71.76               
Residuals       0    0.00                       
Warning message:
In anova.lm(model2) :
  ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable
```

The summary lacks p values and F values because the Df for Residuals is 0 when each treatment has only one replicate.

I read that Hurlbert (2004) had a change of heart from his original paper that he wrote in 1984 about some situations where pseudoreplication may not apply--growth chambers being one of them. He said: "Results from such an experiment could be analyzed with an ANOVA that uses the interaction mean square as an estimate of the true error mean square". This sounds promising, but I haven't been able to translate that into an R code or find an example online. Is there anyone out there who has experienced this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you need to have at least one replication in a $2^2 3$ mixed factorial design like yours. That's because if you don't have replications you not have degrees of freedom for the mean square of residuals.

Maybe, you can collapse your design in two of the tree factor. Try with the moist factor.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I would consider treating all your saplings as true replicates unless there is good reason to treat them as pseudoreplicates. That removes your ANOVA problem, which is otherwise impossible to solve because you simply have no power with which to do an analysis.

---

Pseudoreplication isn't a completely clear-cut concept. You've stumbled on one of its grey areas: are individuals in the same growth chamber independent or not? This is a tricky question and gets into philosophical territory - what does it mean to be independent?

I will say that in practice, replication at the chamber level is *never* done in my field of microbial ecology. Instead, we treat each culture within that chamber as an independent replicate. I think this is justifiable because chambers are controlled (and monitored) to a very high degree, and so the treatment imposed at the chamber level is very close to our ideal expectation and *very* different from those in other chambers. Other than fluctuations in the chamber (that we monitor to ensure are absent), there is no reasonable way for errors between cultures to be correlated.

Defined strictly, this is incorrect and the cultures are all pseudoreplicated. Fluctuations or other such problems that affect a chamber affect all units within it. But this logic can be taken too far. To take an extreme and silly example, in most studies, we ignore the fact that errors may be correlated because systems receive the same electrical power supply, which may be noisy.

To return to the fundamental question - what does it mean to be independent? Ultimately, I think this boils down to the question of generalisability. How much do you trust what happens in one of your chambers to be representative of the larger population you are trying to extrapolate to? And can you persuade other people of this? If you and your colleagues do believe that it is representative and can be generalised from, and there is no plausible way for the saplings to affect each other (which I don't know enough to answer), then I think you can reasonably treat them as true replicates in your ANOVA.

If you cannot, then essentially any such analysis is impossible, because you simply have too few experimental units and no power to detect any difference.